# Nullpointerexception error

Tags: android, onclick, nullpointerexception, listener

I am getting a nullpointerexception error on this line

```
btn10.setOnClickListener(this);
```

this is the entire java

```
package com.james.helloandroid2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;


//** activity 
public class HelloAndroid2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener,        ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pokertable);



    //** imagebuttons
    ImageView button10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    button10.setOnClickListener(this);


    View btn9 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    //btn9.setOnClickListener(this); 
    View btn8 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    //btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
    View btn7 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    //btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
    View btn6 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    //btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    View btn5 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    //btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    View btn4 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    //btn4.setOnClickListener(this); 
    View btn3 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    //btn3.setOnClickListener(this); 
    View btn2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //btn2.setOnClickListener(this); 
    View btn1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
    //btn1.setOnClickListener(this); {
}
//** not in use yet.
public void colorChanged(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ColorPickerDialog dialog = new ColorPickerDialog(this, null, 0);
    dialog.show();

}

}
```

im not sure why if anyone could help.

also just a ps. i have certain things forward slashed so they are exempt in my code.. more of notes for me or code im waiting to actually use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:background="@drawable/tablebackground"
    android:gravity="top" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/seat5" 
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton5" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton10" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
        android:onClick="onMyButtonClick"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton1" />



   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button10"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton9" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton6" />



   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton4" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton3" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton2" />



   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton7" />



   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/shapebutton8" />

</RelativeLayout>



01-18 23:09:31.842: D/AndroidRuntime(810): Shutting down VM
01-18 23:09:31.842: W/dalvikvm(810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015560)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.james.helloandroid2/com.james.helloandroid2.HelloAndroid2}:      java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.james.helloandroid2.HelloAndroid2.onCreate(HelloAndroid2.java:23)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-18 23:09:31.852: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: are you getting the null point exception when you are clicking button??or you are getting the exception when you run this code?!

Comment: when i run the code. it force closes when i open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you defining your `ImageView`s in `R.layout.pokertable`? `Activity.findViewById` isn't magical, it simply performs a recursive search down the view hierarchy attached to an activity's current window. If you haven't attached these views by using `setContentView` yet, `findViewById` will return null because there were no matching views present to find.

Maybe posting your Activity's XML layout file will help us pin-point the problem.

Comment: you shouldn't need to nest a `RelativeLayout` in a `LinearLayout`. Choose one, not both. In this case it looks like you want to get rid of the `LinearLayout` entirely.

Comment: ok i lost the linearlayout (i was using it to have a distant background behind the immediate background, no big though) but im still getting the nullpointer

Comment: change `android:layout_height="0dip"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`... I think it is preventing the views from being displayed in the layout

Comment: could you update the code/xml to exactly what you have right now?

Comment: updated, and i changed the "btn10" to "button10" (in the java) just incase that was messing with things, but that didnt make a difference

Comment: cleaning your project and restarting eclipse might be a good idea too... from what I can tell your code should work

Comment: i cleaned/restarted still receiving null on line 22 (same line)       i really appreciate your help btw

Comment: Comment out the Colordialog in the onlcick and check with a simple toast.  can you post the Logcat error?

Comment: ok i did what you said, it still FC on open. and i added the error to the bottom of my xml in OP

Comment: i don't know what to tell ya... i copied and pasted your code into a new project and it worked fine for me... the XML code you posted is your res/layout/pokertable.xml file, correct?

Comment: hmm thats weird... yea thats the correct dir i have it. thats weird... i will double..double check everything again i guess.  it opens in the emulator for you?

Comment: `<activity
            android:name=".HelloAndroid2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>`

Comment: hmm... i just realized you are implementing two `onClickListener`s for your `Activity`. maybe this is what is causing the null pointer exception? try commenting them out and see if it works.

Comment: the OnColorChangedListener? i commented it out and it still errors

Comment: try commenting out everything except the onCreate() and the Activity class definition (comment out the `implements OnClickListener, ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener` too). in fact, a good debugging technique at this point would be to comment out as much as you can, which might help identify the source of the problem.

Comment: yes i copied your code and tried it works fine. i commented out the android:background="@drawable/.. when i tried here. check your drawables for the buttons. i think the problem must be there. just try to give a simple image as background and check.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! AnDro you hit it on the nail! the problem had to do with my drawable, (at the risk of sounding like an idiot) i failed to place my shapedrawables in each drawable folder.. im assuming it was force closing because the emulator wasnt the right resolution that i had the drawable in. wow.. i feel dumb. but thank you again for all the help everyone... and sorry for all the trouble :)

Comment: No problem. it happens to all :)

Comment: i can't believe i do this for fun haha :P. it's a learning experience for us all, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.pokertable);
```

Is "pokertable" the name of your layout xml filename. If you set this wrongly, it could result in this exception.

Answer (score 0):

try overriding onClick() method.Add @override right on top of your onClick() method.

Comment: when i override it, it gives me an error to remove the @override before i can continue

Comment: i think you can only implement one Listener per class.try removing  ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener and see if it works.If it works than you should make separate class to handle dialogs listener and call dialogs in this class the way you have done already.